# Overflow bit in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm attempting to add 2 numbers in assembly. However, the resulting number may be larger than the 16 bit memory slot. I set the overflow bit to notify me of when there is overflow but how do I deal with the overflow?

I know it varies between devices, but in general how would I go about saving the "overflowed" values? Could I save it into another memory slot?

I'm using the TI C5515 DSP board if that helps.

I'm rather new at writing assembly so perhaps this is an obvious question. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What should the observable behavior be when such an addition overflows?

Comment: I haven't done C5515 assembly, but I would assume there's an automatic setting of a CPU status bit for overflow if an overflow occurs. You don't have to set it yourself. Then you check for it. If there's an overflow on an addition, you already know it's 1 bit. You need to decide what you want to do with that information based upon your application. Is it an error? Or do you want to maintain numbers that are larger than 16 bits? Up to you.

Comment: @lurker I was just going to add the overflow to the next memory space so as to keep track of it. I'm not sure exactly sure how to check if the overflow bit is set but I'll find it in the datasheet eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "standard" way to store a value too large for your "slot", unless your architecture supports bigger "slots" as well.  You could store the overflow bit in another "slot", although I'm not sure what you would do with it after that.

Comment: Haha I realized afterwards the proper term is probably memory space. I think I'm going to use a double and use the second memory space for my overflow bit.